# Where clause on concatenated column values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a SQL query in MS Access/VBA which does not work as expected. I want to compare a concatenated SQL-varchar with a VBA-variable:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1  
Where Text1 & ' ' & Text2 like '%Test%'
```

But the resulting sql doesn't work and I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated!

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19909942/edit) your question to clarify: **(1)** Confirm whether or not [Table1] is an ODBC linked table in Access that points to a table/view in SQL Server. **(2)** Indicate the context in which you are running the query. If it is being run from VBA code then show us the relevant portion of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe what you are really looking for is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1  
WHERE Text1 & ' ' & Text2 LIKE '*Test*'
```

MS Access uses the `*` for the wild card.

Comment: You use `%` as a wildcard for SQL Server queries.

Comment: But this does not work in my case. The resultset is just empty. the datasource is a MS SQL Server. The columns are both of type nvarchar(50)

Comment: The resulting SQL in MS Profiler looks like SELECT "Nachname" ,"Vorname" ,"dbo"."Tbl_Fahrer"."ID" FROM "dbo"."Tbl_Fahrer".

There is no where Statement!

Comment: @HelloW For a regular Select query (not a Pass-through query) executed from within Access itself, `*` is the correct wildcard character to use even if the query is run against an ODBC linked table.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes that is correct, I was simply adding info to the answer but didn't think it deserved an edit.  I should have been more clear about my intentions.